# Hour/minute adds one hour from datetime with lubridate

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, tibble

I would like to extract the hour/minute/second from a datetime. Example dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(Study_date_time_PACS = structure(c(1515146548, 1515146548, 1514970658, 1514970658, 1515151732, 1515151732, 1517476589, 1517476589, 1543848246, 1543848246),
                                                class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), 
                                                tzone = "UTC")),
          .Names = "Study_date_time", 
          row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
print(df)


# A tibble: 10 x 1
   Study_date_time    
   <dttm>             
 1 2018-01-05 10:02:28
 2 2018-01-05 10:02:28
 3 2018-01-03 09:10:58
 4 2018-01-03 09:10:58
 5 2018-01-05 11:28:52
 6 2018-01-05 11:28:52
 7 2018-02-01 09:16:29
 8 2018-02-01 09:16:29
 9 2018-12-03 14:44:06
10 2018-12-03 14:44:06
```

So I run this code but it adds one hour to the "hour"? How can I fix this. I assume it must be something with summertime...

```
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(hour_min = hms::as.hms(Study_date_time))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   Study_date_time     hour_min
   <dttm>              <time>  
 1 2018-01-05 10:02:28 11:02   
 2 2018-01-05 10:02:28 11:02   
 3 2018-01-03 09:10:58 10:10   
 4 2018-01-03 09:10:58 10:10   
 5 2018-01-05 11:28:52 12:28   
 6 2018-01-05 11:28:52 12:28   
 7 2018-02-01 09:16:29 10:16   
 8 2018-02-01 09:16:29 10:16   
 9 2018-12-03 14:44:06 15:44   
10 2018-12-03 14:44:06 15:44
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probaby due to the timezone-element that gets stripped... Let me guess: You live in a UTC+0100 - region of the planet?

You can use the `force_tz()` function from the lubridate-package.. but be careful!! Timezones are always a b#tch to work with, so handle with care!

```
df %>% mutate(hour_min = hms::as.hms( force_tz( Study_date_time ) ) )

# # A tibble: 10 x 2
#   Study_date_time     hour_min
#   <dttm>              <time>  
# 1 2018-01-05 10:02:28 10:02   
# 2 2018-01-05 10:02:28 10:02   
# 3 2018-01-03 09:10:58 09:10   
# 4 2018-01-03 09:10:58 09:10   
# 5 2018-01-05 11:28:52 11:28   
# 6 2018-01-05 11:28:52 11:28   
# 7 2018-02-01 09:16:29 09:16   
# 8 2018-02-01 09:16:29 09:16   
# 9 2018-12-03 14:44:06 14:44   
# 10 2018-12-03 14:44:06 14:44
```

Comment: @ Wimpel. Thanks alot. Yes I live in UTC + 1 time zone.

Comment: @ Wimpel: I have asked a new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744899/time-zone-gets-lost-with-lubridate-when-creating-a-new-datetime-component-from-i)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this likely a `tz` issue (perhaps you can just do `hms::as.hms(Study_date_time, tz = 'UTC'))` and it'll disappear), however I think you'd also do good without any package, e.g.:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(hour_min = format(Study_date_time, "%H:%M"))
```

Comment: @ arg0naut: Thanks! I don't think format will work. I need the hour/minute to make a filter with time on Fridays between 8 and 14:30. I will get back latter, maybe on monday, I don't have a computer now.

Comment: @ arg0naut, well I have used ``tz`` option on my date. But it does not get carried over to a new variable created with lubridate.

Comment: @ arg0naut: I have asked a new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744899/time-zone-gets-lost-with-lubridate-when-creating-a-new-datetime-component-from-i)