# Time zone gets lost with lubridate when creating a new datetime component from it

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, tibble

The following data frame is from a `dput`. I have used `forced_tz` on the datatime with no argument. I live in UTC+1 time zone.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(list(value = structure(c(1514967058, 1515148132, 1517472989, 1543844646, 1525085884, 1520584330, 1522838681, 1540379051, 1516707360, 1516705706), 
                                 class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), 
          .Names = "value", 
          row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


    tz(df$value)
[1] ""

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(year=year(value))


    > tz(df2$year)
[1] "UTC"
```

I have also used `tz= "Europe/Paris"` but when I extact someting from the datetime (`day`, `month` and so on) they loose their time zone and get UTC again. Is it possible to set the time zone once and then get carried over to all every new datetime components that I create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `year()` seems to return a `numeric`, so it's not anymore a `date` object.

This is the default method for [`year()`](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/blob/master/R/accessors-year.r):

```
year.default <- function(x)
    as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz(x))$year + 1900
```

So, for example:

```
y <- as.POSIXlt("2018-01-03 09:10:58 CET", tz = Sys.timezone())$year + 1900
#y
#[1] 2018
```

Notice that I forced the current `tz` with `Sys.timezone()`.

But:

```
class(y)
#[1] "numeric"
```

So when you call `tz(y)`, since it's numeric it doesn't have a `tz` attribute, and by default it's given `"UTC"`.

```
# example:
# tz(123)
# [1] "UTC"
```

---

A simple solution is to set yourself the timezone:

```
attr(y, "tzone") <- Sys.timezone()
y
#[1] 2018
#attr(,"tzone")
#[1] "Europe/Berlin"
```

So now `tz` works:

```
tz(y)
[1] "Europe/Berlin"
```

---

I'd advise against this but you could also modify the default method of [tz()](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/blob/master/R/accessors-tz.r):

```
my_tz <- function(x) {
  tzone <- attr(x, "tzone")[[1]]
  if (is.null(tzone) && !is.POSIXt(x))
    return(Sys.timezone()) # original was "UTC"
  if (is.character(tzone) && nzchar(tzone))
    return(tzone)
  tzone <- attr(as.POSIXlt(x[1]), "tzone")[[1]]
  if (is.null(tzone))
    return(Sys.timezone()) # original was "UTC"
  tzone
}

my_tz(y)
#[1] "Europe/Berlin"
```

So now you have a "custom" version of `tz()` which returns the current timezone whenever the input is not a correct date format.